# Helper is wrapped in a script tag

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This one must be very easy to answer, though I'm stuck...

- ember 1.0.0
- handlebars 1.0.0

I defined the following (simplified) helper to generate a url:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('imageUrl', function(basename) {
  return 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/' + basename;
});
```

Calling this helper from a template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li><img src={{imageUrl name}}></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Wraps the output in a script tag instead of outputting the expected url:

```
...
<li>
  <img src="<script" id="metamorph-6-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
  http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sport
  <script id="metamorph-6-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>&gt;
```

I don't want this property to be part of my model, so I solved this by representing each item with a controller and defined the imageUrl in this controller. But this feels too complicated:

```
<ul>
  {{#each itemController="myItem"}}
    <li><img {{bind-attr src=imageUrl}}></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>


App.MyItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  imageUrl: function(){
    return 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/' + this.get('name');
  }.property('name');
});
```

How an I use a helper to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use your helper unbounded

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li><img src={{unbound imageUrl name}}></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

from a merged PR in github https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1817

```
Helpers declared as bound can be invoked by their unbound former via the unbound helper: {{unbound foo prop1 prop2}}
```